# Communication between 3 different LAN Networks connected to 1 router

Tags: networking, routing

I have setup a complete LAN-only network, NO internet access.

I have 1 Windows Server, 1 vCenter, 5 esxi, Router.

The network diagram.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e9w1.png)

I have 3 network interfaces : 192.168.100.0/24, 192.168.101.0/24, 192.168.102.0/24

No DHCP, 192.168.100.2 (Windows server is the DNS server), and I wouldn't need static routes since the interfaces are directly connected.

Route List

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrmJj.png)

What am I missing, as I intend to be able to ping from device in one LAN to device in another LAN. And here my server is unable tp ping its own gateway.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDaWT.png)

Comment: Many routers do not respond to Pings by default. Check if this is disabled somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for that, I added a forward rule to forward icmp to network 192.168.101.0/24, now I'm able to ping the server gateway 192.168.100.1 but not any device in the 192.168.101.0/24 network.

Comment: you need to forward in both directions